# Where can I post a configuration question?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

One of my question was closed as being a configuration question and not a programming one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185340/why-do-i-get-a-wamp-homepage-when-clicking-on-specific-websites-url-on-localhos
On which forum should I post it instead?

Answer (score 2):

The StackOverflow [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) states the following as types of questions:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession

The Superuser [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq) states the following as types of questions:

- computer hardware,
- computer software, or
- personal and home computer networking

WAMP would be considered *computer software* configuration issue and should be directed there, as it is not a programing related issue.

Comment: Thanks cryptic, I have transfered it to http://serverfault.com/questions/484230/pages-of-website-returns-a-wamp-homepage-on-my-localhost

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani Please read [their FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq) and make sure your question fits.

Comment: Guys, sorry I already posted on serverfault, should I delete it from there and add it to superuser?

Comment: Bart, thanks, which distinction? I have added information on answer since my question. not sure what else I can add.

Comment: @ArthurMamou-Mani That was directed to cryptic who suggested deleting his answer here.

Comment: @Bart updated =o)

Comment: WAMP questions should generally be on-topic for SO, provided they concern someone's development or testing environment. Note that there were other serious problems with this asker's question (that he later corrected when he reposted it) but he may have actually had better luck on [wordpress.se].